# jQuery adding an effect to many divs in one go

Tags: jquery, hide

Is it possible to apply a jQUery method such as .hide() to many divs with different id parameters in one go.

The example for a single div is:

$("#action-div").click(
    function() { $("#some-div-to-hide").hide("fast"); }
    );

Can this be done for many divs with different ids, without having to handle the .click event many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma seperate the list of ID's.

```
$("#action-div, #anotherId, #yetAnotherId").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, until I removed the spaces after the comma.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use a `class` attribute on the `div`s you want to operate on, then specify the class in the selector.

```
<div class="actiondiv" ...>
```

and then

```
$(".actiondiv").click(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is give all the ids the same class and later:

```
$(".some_class").click( function(){.....});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always apply a single class to these items, and select it based off the class:

```
$(".action-class").click( function() { $("#some-div-to-hide").hide("fast"); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the click event attached to all divs, use a common class (`<div class="clickhidden">`):

```
$(".clickhidden").click( function() { $("#some-div-to-hide").hide("fast"); } );
```

If you want one click to hide multiple classes, attach the class to the target:

```
$("#action-div").click( function() { $(".clickhidden").hide("fast"); } );
```

Combinations are also possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide() 2 different classes like this:

**Class to hide 1**

```
<p class="hideOne>hide me!</p>
```

**Class to hide 2**

```
<p class="hideTwo>hide me!</p>
```

You can hide() class one and two as follows:

```
<script>
    $("p.hideOne,p.hideTwo").hide("slow");
</script>
```